# Send Text via Bluetooth to App without the necessarity of acceptance

Tags: android, bluetooth

is it possible, to send a text via Bluetooth from one device to another, both using the same app which sends the text, without the need of the receiving device to accept it?

So, for the device that receives it should be configured any of the following ways:

Either I can configure the sender device as "trusted" so everything sent from this device is accepted without asking for it

Or everything that comes from that App will be received without questioning and forwarded only to the app on the receiving device, for it to handle the data

Thank you

Comment: Current Android Bluetooth API's require devices to be paired before an RFCOMM connection can be established. (Pairing is automatically performed when you initiate an encrypted connection with the Bluetooth APIs.)

Comment: I don't mean the pairing part. So I already paired both devices. But now the app wants to send data to the paired device. If I send images, I need to accept them on the receiving phone. Do I have to do the same with Text sent via Bluetooth to the App? Or can I ignore acceptance there and the receiving phone can handle the data without  the need of touching it?

Comment: You should be able to receive the data directly to your app without user acceptances see the android bluetooth API chat message example proviced by Android. this example may help u to understand the communication http://myandroidappdevelop.blogspot.in/2013/05/bluetooth-chat-example.html